# Why does a second window in Safari fade black?

Tags: macos, safari

This happens on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) with macOS Monterey v.12.6.

When I open or use two windows of safari, the inactive window fades black. Anybody knows how to turn this off? It seems more like a bug, then a settings though… Does not happen every time. Very annoying since I very often use two windows side by side and read on both.

[image: Couldn't take picture of all of the screen, had some sensitive info there, but you get the point]

Couldn't take picture of all of the screen, had some sensitive info there, but you get the point.

After some testing a pattern emerge: If I click back and forward (the other window fade into black). If I continue to go back and forward 3 times (5 click), both will be in focus.

However, it needs to be the **same domain**, otherwise it won't fade black. I notices that my other window was normal, then I closed one tab with same domain as my other window, and it faded black.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Just guessing, but could it be related to Focus (https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-a-focus-on-or-off-mchl999b7c1a/mac)? (For further troubleshooting, it'd be helpful if you added the model of your Mac / macOS version to the question.)

Comment: I will try to debug it, sounds plausible. I have added the version number :) Thanks

Comment: Is the page that's faded black open in any other tabs?

Comment: yes @Ezekiel it is

Comment: It does happen both with and without focus turn on @jaume

Comment: @PrebenHafnor It's faded black because you have the same tab open twice. This can be done intentionally, but also sometimes happens unintentionally due to a bug in Safari.

Comment: If you close the other copy of the tab, it won't darken.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same. Apparently it is a bug. When dragging the tab out to create a new window, it should close the other tab.

The solution is to close Safari, open once in safe mode, and then open a few tabs and drag a tab to create a new window.

As described here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Safari/comments/xrrdm4/comment/ir14ifa/